# Finite Difference Application

Tags: black-scholes, finance, quantitative, black-scholes-pde, finite-difference-method

We all know that the traditional BS equation is:

$$\frac{\partial \mathrm V}{ \partial \mathrm t } + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2} \mathrm S^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathrm V}{\partial \mathrm S^2}
    + \mathrm r \mathrm S \frac{\partial \mathrm V}{\partial \mathrm S}\ -
    \mathrm r \mathrm V  = 0$$

Suppose we want to write it is as:

$$\frac{\partial \mathrm V}{ \partial \mathrm t } + a(S, t)\frac{\partial^{2} \mathrm V}{\partial \mathrm S^2}
    + b(S, t) \frac{\partial \mathrm V}{\partial \mathrm S}\ +
    c(S, t)\mathrm V  = 0$$

In order to emphasize the wide applicability of the finite difference methods.

Why do we have that **the only constraint we must pose on the coefficients is that if we are solving a backward equation we must have $a > 0$ ?**

Comment: a<0 requires you to be at-ease with the concept of negative variance (or, perhaps, complex-valued volatility). Neither has a clear physical meaning (at least to me!)